# How to create refrence of class in scala?

Tags: java, scala

I am new to scala. I am trying to create refrence of class. In java i can write

```
ContactFeed resultFeed = myService.getFeed(metafeedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
```

How to write same in scala?

Answer (score 3):

Use `classOf`, e.g.:

```
val resultFeed = myService.getFeed(metafeedUrl, classOf[ContactFeed])
```